# javascript) odd/ even/ null..../ NaN

Tags: javascript, if-statement

Q. Write a program that separates odd and even numbers by receiving a number from the user

- Output 'Cancel Input' when input is cancelled
  -Distinguish odd-even if a value has been entered

I made it using the if else statement, but I can't output the input cancel when I cancel the input.
I want to cancel the input, and make it aware when something that is not a number comes in as well.
Is it not possible for if to recognize null and NaN as false?
So how do you make it recognizable?

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="ko">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>JAVASCRIPT</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <script>
     let num = Number(prompt('put a number',15));
        let re;
        if(num == null){
            re = 'no'
        }
        if(num != Number){
            re ='please put a number'
        }
        if(num % 2 === 0){
            re = 'even';
        }else if(num % 2 === 1){
            re = 'odd';
        }
    </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: `num` will never be `null` and it will never be equal to `Number`. That's not how you test for a thing being a proper number; probably the simplest thing in your case is to replace the first two `if` tests with `if (isNaN(num))`